# Fancybox removing scroll, shifts page

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

When I click on a link that loads a Fancybox the whole background page shifts to the right do to fancy box removing the scroll bar. I have tried adding this JS as suggested in other forums but no luck. A link is below (click on a brand title), not sure why it would remove the scroll bar.

I load the object like

```
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display:none;">
                          <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="brand_list" style="width:800px !important;">
                            <h2>The Beers</h2>
                            <div class="beers">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

The Fix I tried

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
        }); 
        </script>
```

[The Issue](http://www.revolveis.net/watkins/watkins-distributing-idaho-falls/)

Comment: Cant seem to re-create the problem do you have a live example?

Comment: @chrisarton ya sorry the link didnt work at first. Look at "The Issue" on my post

Comment: It does not seem to be removing the scroll bar for me, what browser are you using? Do you have the same problem on all browsers?

Comment: @chrisarton really I tried in Chrome/Safari/Moz and it wasnt working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scrollbar is being removed because jquery.fancybox.pack.js is adding the property `overflow: hidden;` to the `<body>` element via the class `.fancybox-lock` whenever a fancybox is displayed. There are several ways you can handle this.

1) Modify the javascript in jquery.fancybox.pack.js to not add this class to the body element when a fancybox is displayed.
2) Modify the css in jquery.fancybox.css (line 169) to not add the `overflow: hidden;` property for the `.fancybox-lock` selector.
3) In one of your own css files, and the `!important` declaration to the overflow property on the body to override the fancybox css (i.e. `body { overflow: auto !important; }`).
4) Add the `overflow: auto;` as an inline style directly on the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by BigMacAttack, the problem is the `overflow: hidden` style added to the `<body>` element. This removes the scrollbar from the body and prevents scrolling.

However, a solution that accepts the `overflow: hidden` is to compensate for the additional body width (due to the loss of the scrollbar) with an additional padding. Just save your body width before opening the overlay and add an additional padding when required.

```
// before opening
var originalWidth = $('body').width(); 

// when open
if ($('body').width() > originalWidth) {
    $('body').css("padding-right", ($('body').width() - originalWidth) +"px");
}

// after closing
$('body').css("padding-right", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
Here's what you need to do:

1) Launch Fancybox with this option:

```
helpers:{overlay: {css: {'overflow': hidden}}}
```

2) Add this line in any css file that executes after fancybox css

```
html.fancybox-lock {overflow-y: scroll !important}
```

That will make Fancybox to **open and close without shifting your entire website** AND **won't affect the overflow of your html or body tag** (it only sets 'overflow-y: scroll' when fancybox-lock class is present in the html tag)

Answer (score 0):

For people who use iframe with fancybox, this will put the scroll bar back on your main page

```
if ($( "body", window.parent.document ).hasClass( "compensate-for-scrollbar" ) ) {
   $( "body", window.parent.document ).removeClass( "compensate-for-scrollbar" );
}
```